# Default Price Issue in Magento

Tags: php, magento

In the view catalog page,  I have added a custom select drop down. On selection of an option by the user the price should change accordingly like when i choose 60mg product ,price changes to $6 and when i change the product size to 450gm its price changes to $60 and its working perfect. 
[this image shows above condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAQVX.png)

**But**

My Problem is When I select 450gm product to cart its cost show $6 but actual price of 450 gm is $60.

[image shows above problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raD4o.png)

Please help me ..!!

Comment: please explain more, are you using magento's custom option or you coded to display dropdown? And attached image not explaining much.

Comment: i am using magento's custom option